# I don't know why i can't use this equation (in the pic) in flatspace, I'm learning general relativity (metric tensor)

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, notation

[image]

I don't know why this equation cannot be used in **flatspace**, Who can help me?

Comment: Why do you think that it can’t?

Comment: Because im watching a tutorial form Youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foRPKAKZWx8&t=1721s if you see 52:01, he says that in a flat space, the metric tensor must be changed to the Kronecker Delta, Why?

Comment: It doesn’t get *changed*. It is jjust is equal to the Kronecker delta, because that is the metric tensor of flat space, essentially *by definition* of “flat”.

Comment: so if there's a flatspace (do you mean a two dimension space?), the ds^2 will equal to the  Kronecker Delta times dy^r and dy^s?

Comment: Flat space can have any number of dimensions, not just two. The second equation is nonsense because there is a typo in the indices.

Comment: Where's the typo?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foRPKAKZWx8&t=1721s I followed this and the equation in the pic is same that he wrote

Comment: The left side is a scalar. The right side is a tensor of rank $(2,2)$. The $g_{mn}$ is supposed to be $g_{rs}$ or, for flat space, $\delta_{rs}$. That makes the right side a scalar.

Comment: Don’t be surprised that there are typos in YouTube physics videos. There are typos in physics textbooks. The goal is to be able to recognize things that make no sense and cannot possibly be right. Once you understand index contraction you will see why this equation is nonsense.

Comment: Thanks! What changed if the g_{mn} changed to g_{rs}? It becomes a scalar?

Comment: A tensor expression with its indices completely contracted is a scalar.

Comment: But I can’t teach you tensor calculus in comments.

Comment: Thanks, I'll find some vids and learn tensor calculus then

Comment: Or you know any resources to learn it?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to learn tensor algebra/calculus first and *then* GR. Good luck! GR is a beautiful theory.

Comment: Sure! Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Sorry, I don’t have a good resource recommendation for tensor algebra. When you study physics, you normally pick it up first in classical mechanics (when learning about the moment of inertia tensor), then in relativistic mechanics (when learning about the Minkowski spacetime of SR), and then in advanced EM (when learning about the EM field tensor and energy-momentum tensor). You could start by researching these topics.

Comment: Now I'm watching vids for tensor algebra(I don't even know what is Minkowski spacetime haha but i love Special Relativity very much)

Comment: Wait is ds^2 a scalar? Isn't it a vector?

Comment: No. I’m sorry, but this is the last comment I will make because comments are not for long discussions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can actually be used in flatspace, as a matter of fact. It is a generalised case that can be used in all space. In flat space it simply simplifies into what you call the Pythagoras Theorem.

Comment: Thanks! So this and Pythagoras both works in a flatspace?

Comment: Go to YouTube and watch this video on General theory of relativity (2 hours long) by DrPhysicsA, the part on metric tensor. It's pretty clear for a beginner.

Comment: Yes im watching that, it is great!

Comment: But at 52:01 he says that the metric tensor must be changed to the Kronecker Delta in flat space

Comment: So i asked this question

Comment: Well assuming I can overlook the mistake in the equation, it is just that the the metric tensor and kronecker delta are not different things. The metric tensor is just a more generalised system of representing it in all n-dimensional space regardless of its conformation. Therefore it is redundant to say that it can be changed to the Kronecker Delta. It IS in a way the Kronecker delta. Have you studied tensors in depth or just a high school enthusiast? I seriously recommend you study Classical Mechanics and Gravity in detail before attempting GR.

Comment: Tbh I'm a high school enthusiast, Sure will study CM and matrics and tensor algebra , thanks